# Call external function from ajax() success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a function defined within `$(document).ready()` which arranges some JSON into HTML using DoT.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function arrangeResults(jsonObject, templateFunc) {
        $(jsonObject).each(function(i, item) {
            $.each(item, function(i2, item2) {
            $('#ajax-article-list .col-left').append( templateFunc(item2) );
            });
        });
    };
```

I have an AJAX call on page load which executes this function to display the data:

```
$.post(ajaxRequestURL, function(data) {
    arrangeResults(ajaxData.pages, projectTemplate);
}
```

and this works fine.

However I have a set of links which requests more/different JSON data using the `click()` handler, which should execute `arrangeResults` again with the returned data, but the function isn't executed:

```
$('nav.filters a').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.post(ajaxRequestURL, function(data) {
        ajaxData = parseJSON(data);
        arrangeResults(ajaxData.pages, projectTemplate);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. The data is all valid, and everything works if I take the contents of `arrangeResults` and put them directly within the script, but I was hoping to follow DRY and have an external function that I could call upon both on pageload and when one of the filters is clicked.

I guess it's because the AJAX call is asynchronous but since the function call is within `success` I presumed this wouldn't cause a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it right, you have first AJAX call inside `$(document).ready()` block.
So it could be because you have **arrangeResults** function inside your `$(document).ready()` block. Because of that you are unable to call the function from other part of JScript.
Define it like that:

```
    function arrangeResults(jsonObject, templateFunc) {
        ...
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ...
    );
```

and so on.
Correct me if I wrong, please.

Comment: Thanks, it was as simple as defining the templating function outside $(document).ready().